# Connection with SQL database in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have connected with the database successfully by using wizard in server explorer. but the data source is showing nothing. i have googled and search on msdn help. but not get help.

I want to add data source. but add new data source option is disabled for me.
I am using windows form application...
I want ask that am i doing right. could you please tell me how can i get rid of not showing thing. 
PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Server Explorer` of Visual Studio 2010 and the `Datasource` of your application are completely different. Check the following links to see how you can connect your `Windows Form Application` with `Sql-Server` database:

- [Walkthrough: Connecting to Data in a SQL Server Express Database (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx)
- [Connecting to a Database with Visual Studio Tools](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/ado-net/connecting-database-visual-studio-tools)

Comment: yes they are absolutely different. but i googled and found the answer.

Comment: Answer: I am using c/C++ windows form application with this there are complexities in it. we can't simply create datasource using it. so I've decided to use the C# ... yes c# is the best ... ans is simple that .. use c# instead of c/c++... and use the wizard to connect to database server and also datasource.